# Sending data using Bluetooth Serial Port Profile with Python socket library between Raspberry Pi and computer

Tags: python, sockets, bluetooth, raspberry-pi, serial-port

I have been able to connect a sensor via Bluetooth to my Raspberry Pi and receive its information with the Serial Port Profile using the Python Socket library with this program:

```
import socket

sensorMACAddress = 'XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX'

port = 1

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_BLUETOOTH, socket.SOCK_STREAM, socket.BTPROTO_RFCOMM)
s.connect((sensorMACAddress,port))

s.send(bytes('#ob', 'UTF-8'))  # Tells the sensor to send the data in bytes

while(1):

   data = s.recv(12)


   while len(data) < 12:

       data = data + s.recv(12)


   Y = struct.unpack('<f', data[0:4])[0]
   P = struct.unpack('<f', data[4:8])[0]
   R = struct.unpack('<f', data[8:12])[0]

   YPR = str(['S3', int(Y), int(P), int(R)])

   print(YPR)
   print('\n')
```

(The sensor sends the data automatically once connected.)

Now I want to send the information of this sensor to my computer, so I just updated the prior program by creating a new socket object for the connection between the Raspberry and the computer to send the information with the send() function:

```
# This goes outside the loop
computerMACAddress = 'XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX'
s_comp = socket.socket(socket.AF_BLUETOOTH, socket.SOCK_STREAM, socket.BTPROTO_RFCOMM)
s_comp.connect((computerMACAddress,port))


# This goes inside the loop
s_comp.send(YPR.encode())
```

Apparently this program is sending information, and it does connect via Bluetooth to my computer (or my phone) but my computer (Windows) doesn't seem to receive it, and neither does my phone (Android).

Following this steps (https://scribles.net/setting-up-bluetooth-serial-port-profile-on-raspberry-pi/) I was able to send and receive information between my Raspberry Pi and my computer via Bluetooth using their respective keyboards, using the Bluetooth Serial Port Profile, so the problem seems to be on the sockets and not on the Bluetooth Serial Port Profile connection. The following simple program didn't work either:

```
import socket

computerMACAddress = 'XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX'

port = 1

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_BLUETOOTH, socket.SOCK_STREAM, socket.BTPROTO_RFCOMM)
s.connect((computerMACAddress,port))


data = 'Hello world!'

while 1:
   s.send(bytes(data, 'UTF-8'))
   print(data)
```

On this example (http://blog.kevindoran.co/bluetooth-programming-with-python-3/) I saw that they create a client program to send the information and a server program to receive it, but I didn't have to do this to receive information from the sensor to the Raspberry, so I don't know why I would need to do it with the computer. In any case, I tried but I couldn't make it work. Apparently, sockets don't work very well in Windows, but with my Android phone I couldn't receive information either, even though I could establish a Bluetooth connection.

So, in summary:

1. Why did the send() and recv() functions work with the sensor but not with the computer or phone?
2. If I need a server program, why didn't I need it to receive information from the sensor, and how can I make it work?
3. If that's not the problem, what is it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like there is a Bluetooth Serial Port Profile (SPP) server running on the sensor and so the SPP client on the Raspberry Pi connects and exchanges information successfully.

Python sockets for Bluetooth SPP on Windows was only introduced in Python 3.9 so you will need a recent version of Python on your Windows computer.

However, if it has connected, then maybe you need to go hunting for the serial port it has connected it to. Maybe the following will help: https://www.instructables.com/Raspberry-Pi-Bluetooth-to-PuTTY-on-Windows-10/

However a more typical setup would be that the Raspberry Pi would be a bridge between the sensor and the network. This means that the value from the sensor goes to the RPi by Bluetooth. Then the RPi makes the sensor data available over WiFi/internet via a website/socket running on the RPi.

As a side note, you could be a little more efficient with your unpacking of the data. For example:

```py
>>> data = b'\x11\x11\x11\x11\x22\x22\x22\x22\x33\x33\x33\x33'
>>> import struct
>>> Y, P, R = struct.unpack('<fff', data)
>>> print(f"['S3', {Y}, {P}, {R}]\n")
['S3', 1.1443742118159064e-28, 2.1973163753312686e-18, 4.17232506322307e-08]
```

Comment: I'm able to connect to my computer and I can see the COM port to which it is connected, but I'm unable to open it. PuTTY gives an error and says it's unable to open serial port and the Arduino Serial Monitor says "Port Busy". Something similar happens with my phone, I am able to connect to it but when I use an app to receive the info ("Serial Bluetooth Terminal") it tells me: "Connection failed: read failed, socket might closed or tiemout, read ret: -1. If I can't make it work I will try the WiFi setup instead. Why is it more typical? Does it have advantages over the Bluetooth one?

Comment: P.D.. thanks for the side note, I'll apply it. But why isn't it necessary to specify the number of bytes you assign to each variable? It just divides the data equally between the number of variables you create?

Comment: The letters in the `struct.unpack` specify how many bytes are in each entry in the tuple. It is then doing a tuple unpack to each variable. https://treyhunner.com/2018/03/tuple-unpacking-improves-python-code-readability/